# Toilet seat stuck even though bolts removed

Tags: toilet

I am trying to remove and replace my toilet seat, but, even after removing the bolts attaching the seat to the bowl (as was shown in many videos), the seat remains stubbornly attached at the hinge (as if glued down).

What might have caused this?

I have seen a suggestion to apply rust repellent, but the piece looks entirely plastic so would that help?

[image: Toilet seat with hinge removed]

Comment: If replacing the seat I would suggest more force.  The years might just made it stick and act like glued down.  Wiggle the seat side to side.

Comment: smack the hinges sharply with a screwdriver handle, you won't break the toilet itself. tap tap taparoo.

Comment: Glue is a possibility. If the seat wanted to slide around, then I can imagine an aggravated person using glue to freeze it in place. I doubt there exists an adhesive that sticks well to porcelain. Acetone is a good solvent for softening super glue, so that could be worth a try. First I would put down some sort of soft fulcrum to pry off of, then pry on them with a reasonable amount of force. If you break the porcelain, then that obviously was an unreasonable amount of force. Some pipe pliers from behind could be useful for twisting instead of prying up.

Comment: I also find steam cleaners loosen all sorts of things that become stuck over time; nuts, hinges, adhesives, etc; it makes short work of it.

Comment: It is probably years of gunk holding it in place.   Spray it liberally, with almost anything - water, lemon juice, vinegar.  Leave it to soak for 10s of minutes. Hold the seat firmly with both hands.  Wiggle it sideways and twist it. and pull up.  Even if its glued, this is unlikely to break the toilet itself.

Comment: Use a chisel and tap parallel to the surface of the toilet?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions. I managed to get one of the hinges off and it turns out there is a sticky foam pad holding it in-place.
[image]

Comment: This is not uncommon to see, I was just going to answer with this. Good job.